# Pandas rolling gives NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking at the tutorials on window functions, but I don't quite understand why the following code produces NaNs.

If I understand correctly, the code creates a rolling window of size 2. Why do the first, fourth, and fifth rows have NaN? At first, I thought it's because adding NaN with another number would produce NaN, but then I'm not sure why the second row wouldn't be NaN.

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]}, 
                   index=pd.date_range('20130101 09:00:00', periods=5, freq='s'))


In [58]: dft.rolling(2).sum()
Out[58]: 
                       B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:01  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  3.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:04  NaN
```

Comment: This will allow you to remove `NaN`s from your dataframe, if that's what you're looking to do: `dft[dft['B'].notnull()].rolling(2).sum()`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that by default `rolling` looks for n-1 prior rows of data to aggregate, where n is the window size. If that condition is not met, it will return NaN for the window. This is what's happening at the first row. In the fourth and fifth row, it's because one of the values in the sum is NaN.

If you would like to avoid returning NaN, you could pass `min_periods=1` to the method which reduces the minimum required number of valid observations in the window to 1 instead of 2:

```
>>> dft.rolling(2, min_periods=1).sum()
                       B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:01  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  3.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  2.0
2013-01-01 09:00:04  4.0
```

Comment: I think key thing for me was knowing that it was n-1 (instead of n), thanks!

Comment: if `center=True`, it's `(n-1)/2`, not `n-1` I guess. But the answer still holds of course +1

Comment: maechler's answer below is a good one.  It deserves more upvotes!

Answer (score 7):

Using `min_periods=1` can lead to high variance for the values in the rolling window. Another way to remove `NaN` values is to use `fillna` on the rolling window:

```py
>>> dft.rolling(2).sum().fillna(method='bfill').fillna(method='ffill')
                       B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:01  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  3.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  3.0
2013-01-01 09:00:04  3.0
```

An example with a rolling window size of 6 illustrates the issue:

```py
>>> dft = pd.DataFrame({'B': [10, 1, 10, 1, 10, 1, 10, 1, 10, 1]}, index=pd.date_range('20130101 09:00:00', periods=10, freq='s'))

>>> dft.rolling(6, min_periods=1).sum()
                        B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  10.0
2013-01-01 09:00:01  11.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  21.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  22.0
2013-01-01 09:00:04  32.0
2013-01-01 09:00:05  33.0
2013-01-01 09:00:06  33.0
2013-01-01 09:00:07  33.0
2013-01-01 09:00:08  33.0
2013-01-01 09:00:09  33.0

>>> dft.rolling(6).sum().fillna(method='bfill')
                        B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  33.0
2013-01-01 09:00:01  33.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  33.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  33.0
2013-01-01 09:00:04  33.0
2013-01-01 09:00:05  33.0
2013-01-01 09:00:06  33.0
2013-01-01 09:00:07  33.0
2013-01-01 09:00:08  33.0
2013-01-01 09:00:09  33.0
```

Whereas using `min_periods=1` leads to values below 33.0 for the first 5 values, using `fillna` produces the expected 33.0 throughout the window. Depending on your use case you might want to use `fillna`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rolling(2), use rolling('2d')

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]}, 
                   index=pd.date_range('20130101 09:00:00', periods=5, freq='s'))


dft.rolling('2d').sum()
```

Comment: should it be 'freq' = 'd' not 's', as below ?  

dft = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]}, 
                   index=pd.date_range('20130101 09:00:00', periods=5, freq='d'))



dft.rolling('2d').sum()

Answer (score 0):

Indeed adding NAN and anything else gives NAN.  So:

```
input + rolled = sum
    0      nan   nan
    1        0     1
    2        1     3
  nan        2   nan
    4      nan   nan
```

There's no reason for the second row to be NAN, because it's the sum of the original first and second elements, neither of which is NAN.

Another way to do it is:

```
dft.B + dft.B.shift()
```